# I'm looking for a "soft" limit on this database query

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have this database query:

```
SELECT * FROM Events e 
   WHERE e.TimestampTicks >= @StartTicks 
   ORDER BY e.TimestampTicks 
   LIMIT @Limit
```

`@StartTicks` and `@Limit` are variables passed in.

I need the query to behave a little differently. I want `@Limit` to be more of a minimum. For any given TimestampTicks value (a 64bit signed integer) I need all the rows for that value. I can't split any group of TimestampTicks. How can I modify the query to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM Events e
WHERE e.TimestampTicks between @StartTicks 
  AND (SELECT MAX(TimestampTicks)
                              FROM
                              (
                                SELECT TimestampTicks 
                                FROM Events 
                                   WHERE TimestampTicks >= @StartTicks 
                                   ORDER BY TimestampTicks 
                                   LIMIT @Limit
                              )emax
                         )
ORDER BY e.TimestampTicks
```

Comment: There is an index on the TimestampTicks column. Do you expect that MAX will use that index? Do you expect that MAX will use that index even without the ORDER BY on the inner query?

Comment: If there is an index, it might. But if it does not, the solution by @Gordon Linoff will work better. Both queries are almost exact except for how max is gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to find the first value of TimestampTicks that's larger than @StartTicks, and then return all rows that match that value? If so, you'd do it like this:

```
SELECT e1.*
  FROM Events e1
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(TimestampTicks) AS TimestampTicks
          FROM Events e2
         WHERE TimestampTicks >= @StartTicks) e2
    ON e1.TimestampTicks = e2.TimestampTicks
```

Additionally, since you're pulling all the matching records, I don't believe there's a need for the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the threshold value you are looking for, and then use a `where` clause to get the results:

```
select *
from Events e
where e.TimestampTicks between @StartTicks and
         (select TimestampTicks 
           from (SELECT *
                 FROM Events e 
                 WHERE e.TimestampTicks >= @StartTicks 
                 ORDER BY e.TimestampTicks 
                 LIMIT @Limit
                ) t
           order by TimestampTicks desc
           limit 1
          )
```

This works by getting the @LIMIT number of rows in the innermost subquery that meet the condition.  It then orders them the *other* way, to get the limit value for `TimestampTicks`).  (I could also use `select max(TimestampTicks)` for this purpose.)  This threshold is then used as the `where` condition.

Comment: You are almost right. You just forgot to put back "e.TimestampTicks >= @StartTicks". This is the start off point.

Comment: @OsaE . . . That line is in the innermost subquery.  That is the start-off point.

Comment: I see that. But outermost query is getting data from entire table and then filtering by only max returned from inner query. I tested your query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f48/18/0

Comment: @OsaE . . . I see your point.  It is a "between" query, not just a "top" query.

Comment: Your update is right. I going to rewrite mine using between. It is cleaner.